# OpenVINO | Convert to ONNX file

Tags: model, pytorch, onnx, openvino

I am testing to convert the pytorch model to the openvino model, but I failed.

I need help.

[Version Setting]
mmdet : 2.24.0v
pytorch : 1.8.0+cu111v
mmdeploy : 0.6.0v
mmcv-full : 1.3.17v

[Error-1]
[image]

[Error-2]

- Thank you for your answers.

This error occurs when you enter the entire 'mo' command and turn it around.
[image]

[Error-3]

- I succeeded in getting an INTERNAL error by modifying it a little bit.
  [image]

Comment: Try to run `mo` command directly. It will probably show some more helpful error stack trace

Comment: As suggested could you please run the whole command from the bottom of this log? This will run the model through MO and it should give you some error message, not just the error exit code.

Comment: I tried the above way and got this error.
[ ERROR ] No node with name des

Answer (score 0):

Your error indicates that there's an issue with MMCVModulatedDeformConv2D. This operation is **not supported** by OpenVINO. Therefore, you won't be able to use it with OpenVINO.

You may refer to [OpenVINO Supported Operators.](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_Supported_Frameworks_Layers.html#onnx-supported-operators)

Comment: So, is there a way to build additional openvino ops?

Comment: One of the possible workaround is to use Custom Operation by utilizing the OpenVINO Extensibility API. This allows you to add support for those custom operations and use one implementation for Model Optimizer and OpenVINO Runtime. 

You may refer [here.](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_Extensibility_UG_Intro.html#openvino-extensibility-mechanism)

Comment: When I read the document, it says it can only be implemented with C++, is that right?

I would appreciate it if you could explain it in more detail.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to implement in C++.Defining a new custom operation basically consist of two parts: Definition of operation semantics in OpenVINO which is required for inference and Mapping rule is required for successful import of a model containing such operations from the original framework model format. Refer [here](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_Extensibility_UG_add_openvino_ops.html#doxid-openvino-docs-extensibility-u-g-add-openvino-ops) for Semantic Operation.

Comment: As for the Mapping, there are 2 ways to choose: For ONNX or PaddlePaddle formats use the [Front End Extension API](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_Extensibility_UG_Frontend_Extensions.html#doxid-openvino-docs-extensibility-u-g-frontend-extensions) and if the model is represented in TensorFlow, Caffe, Kaldi or MXNet formats use the [Model Optimizer Extension](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_customize_model_optimizer_Customize_Model_Optimizer.html#doxid-openvino-docs-m-o-d-g-prepare-model-customize-model-optimizer-customize-model-optimizer)

Comment: In fact you can also create the op extensions for OV frontends in Python code. Please have a look at this test https://github.com/itikhono/openvino/blob/f3a46be216a3386255f410782538f730cebb1e28/src/bindings/python/tests/test_frontend/test_frontend_onnx.py#L327-L360

The relevant part is the bottom of the `custom_converter` which returns a subgraph (in this case a single node) which is supposed to represent the `Add` operation. You can implement the unsupported `MMCVModulatedDeformConv2D` in a similar way if you know what this operator does and if the OV Core opset is sufficient to express it

Comment: Thanks lffa_Intel, tomdol.
I'll try it with the information I gave you and ask you again if it doesn't work! :D